# Infinite "Verifying *.pkg"

Tags: macbook-pro, applications, macos, install

I have been staring the following to dialogs for about an hour:

[image][image]

This problem does't only occur on one specific application. Instead, **all** applications seem to experiencing an infinite verification progress. What's wrong with my computer?

In fact, this issue emerges exactly after I upgrade my system. The current system version is `OS X 10.11.4 (15E65)` and here is the upgrades I've just installed:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Many times (not every time) this is because of a `Keychain` certificate/network issue.  You can try turning off `Certificates` and see if this helps.  After you do this, restart the MacBook, finish the installations, then turn `Certificates` back on.

Go to `Keychain Access --> Preferences --> Certificates`.  See the image below.

[image]